# Converting this function to anonymous function

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming

How do I create this function which returns true if a number is 5 to an anonymous function:

```
def yeah_five(p: Int): Boolean = p == 5
```

thanks?

Comment: Which function? There's no function in your code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short notation for anonymous functions:

```
(p: Int) => (p == 5);
```

Long version:

```
new Function1[Int] {
  def apply(p: Int): Int = p == 5
}
```

Comment: even shorter is (_: Int) == 5

Answer (score 0):

You want a function that takes an Integer and returns a Boolean

```
(p: Int) => (p == 5);
```

Read through the tutorial on [anonymous](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/133) functions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the shortest way to write it would be like so:

```
val f: Int => Boolean = (_ == 5)
```

Of course, depending on the context you can loose the type annotation:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5).filter(_ == 5)

=> List(5, 5)
```

As per @Senia's observation you can be even more succint with `5==` wich transforms the `==` method of the object 5 to a function.

```
val g: Int => Boolean = 5==
List(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5).filter(g) => List(5, 5)
```

Comment: If you want the shortest way: `List(1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5).filter(5==)`

Comment: @senia Thank you, it didn't cross my mind. I'll update my answer with your observation if it's ok with you

Comment: @alex23 It's partially applied, yes.

Comment: @senia - Yeah, I just saw, But I don't understand why.

Comment: @MariusDanila: it's because of overloaded methods. There are several methods in type `Int` with name `==`. Method `filter` of `List[Int]` takes function with type `Int => Boolean`, so you don't have to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are want to turn that already declared method into a function, do this

```
yeah_five _
```